# Dynamic Startup Screen for iphone Webapp

Tags: ios, web-applications, iphone-web-app

We all know how to set a static startup picture for a webapp ("apple-touch-startup-image"). 
Any idea on how to implement a dynamic Startup Screen (e.g. with a loading progress bar, etc.) in an iphone/ipad **webapp**? Something like this: app.ft.com .
Thank you all in advance.